# Why CookieContainer does not replace cookies with the same name?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cookies, dotnet-httpclient, cookiecontainer

## Problem

I'm trying to scrap data from one famous website and found a question doing this.

This site uses cookies for authentication, and it sets the cookie, then replaces it during the authentication flow.

My problem is that [`CookieContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecontainer?view=net-5.0) does not replace cookies with the same name, same domain, but in the second case domain starts with dot.

But any browser or Postman does this.

So result of this is double-sent cookie, and the site fails authentication flow.

### Sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using NUnit.Framework;

...

[Test]
public void Cookies()
{
    CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://example.com/item");
    string cookie1 = "myCookie=value1; Domain=example.com;  Expires=Sat, 11-Feb-2090 02:41:39 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly";
    string cookie2 = "myCookie=value2; Domain=.example.com; Expires=Sat, 11-Feb-2090 02:41:39 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly";

    container.SetCookies(uri, cookie1);
    container.SetCookies(uri, cookie2);

    List<Cookie> cookies = container.GetCookies(uri).ToList();
    foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cookie);
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(1, cookies.Count);
}
```

The output is:

```
myCookie=value1
myCookie=value2
```

But expected output is:

```
myCookie=value2
```

### Why `SetCookies` ?

The `SetCookies` method is in the default implementation of [`CookieHelper`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1f2116cd60ec0f3e39abbf60d7feedc537e5dfd3/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/CookieHelper.cs#L26) which is used inside of [`Http2Stream`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1f2116cd60ec0f3e39abbf60d7feedc537e5dfd3/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/Http2Stream.cs#L1048) of `System.Net.Http`.

It is used when the `UseCookies` property of `HttpClientHandler` is set to true:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
    UseCookies = true,
};
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

//Make requests
```

My runtime version is `NET 5`, so `HttpClientHandler` hides `SocketsHttpHandler` implementation if it is necessary.

### My questions:

- Why this could happen? I have not been able to replicate this behavior in any browser available to me
- Is it possible to fix this behavior somehow except the manually handling of cookies inside of `Set-Cookie` headers?

#### Thanks in advance!

---

## UPD 1: Sample with [mockserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/mockserver/mockserver)

### Step 1: set up example.com to localhost in hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

### Step 2: create mockserver

*initializerJson.json*

```
[
  {
    "httpRequest": {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/1",
      "secure": true
    },
    "httpResponse": {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "headers": {
        "Set-Cookie": [
          "myCookie=value1; Domain=example.com;  Expires=Sat, 11-Feb-2090 02:41:39 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly"
        ]
      },
      "body": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "httpRequest": {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/2",
      "secure": true
    },
    "httpResponse": {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "headers": {
        "Set-Cookie": [
          "myCookie=value2; Domain=.example.com; Expires=Sat, 11-Feb-2090 02:41:39 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly"
        ]
      },
      "body": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    "httpRequest": {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/3",
      "secure": true
    },
    "httpResponseTemplate": {
      "template": "cookie = request.headers.Cookie; return { statusCode: 200, body: cookie }; ",
      "templateType": "JAVASCRIPT"
    }
  }
]
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  mockServer:
      image: mockserver/mockserver:latest
      ports:
        - 5000:1080
      environment:
        MOCKSERVER_WATCH_INITIALIZATION_JSON: "true"
        MOCKSERVER_PROPERTY_FILE: /config/mockserver.properties
        MOCKSERVER_INITIALIZATION_JSON_PATH: /config/initializerJson.json
      volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: .
          target: /config
```

Run mockserver in terminal:

```
docker-compose up
```

After that you'll have a http server on your port 5000 with 3 endpoints:

- `/1` - Sets cookie `myCookie=value1; Domain=example.com;  Expires=Sat, 11-Feb-2090 02:41:39 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly`
- `/2` - Sets cookie `myCookie=value2; Domain=.example.com; Expires=Sat, 11-Feb-2090 02:41:39 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly`
- `/3` - Returns cookies sent to server

### Step 3: test it

The testing flow is:

1. Request `https://example.com:5000/1` endpoint
2. Request `https://example.com:5000/2` endpoint
3. Request `https://example.com:5000/3` endpoint and check response

Sample C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;

...

[Test]
public async Task CheckCookies()
{
    CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        CookieContainer = container,
        UseCookies = true,

        //Bypass self-signed https cert
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, certificate2, arg3, arg4) => true,
    };
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    
    await client.GetAsync("https://example.com:5000/1");
    await client.GetAsync("https://example.com:5000/2");
    
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://example.com:5000/3");
    string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(responseText);
    
    Assert.AreEqual("[ \"myCookie=value2\" ]", responseText);
}
```

### Results

After testing that I got the following results:

- Chrome 97: `[ "myCookie=value2" ]`
- Firefox 97.0b6: `[ "myCookie=value2" ]`
- Postman 8.11.1 `[ "myCookie=value2" ]`
- Code above `[ "myCookie=value1; myCookie=value2" ]`

Any suggestions about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in dotnet runtime: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60628

Pending PR: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/64038